# Vue js problems when building outside the src folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am working on an MPA with Vue and codeigniter. I have the following architecture:

```
-htdocs(root)
  - application
    - src
    - views
    - models
    - controllers
```

I work with my frontend basically in the src directory and the others are codeigniter MVC model directories. What I am doing is configuring the webpack to build directly in the views directory so that my codeigniter can consume the generated htmls, configured as follows: (in this case I set it up in the vue.config.js file 
)

```
outputDir: './views'
```

Up to this point everything works fine, wepback does the bundles and generates all the necessary files inside my views directory.The problem now is that the path to the files is the root of the project. Then he tries to fetch the files like this:

```
 <link rel="preaload" href="/css/chunk-common.45fe69c2.css" as="style">
```

So that it points to the correct path (application/views) I made the following configuration in the vue.config.js:

```
assetsDir: './views'
```

But now when he is going to do the build I have the following warning and the files bundle is not completed.

[image]

> Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Perfect thank you!! I think I ended up confusing the functions of publicPath and assetsDir by reading the vue cli documentation. Thank you very much!

Comment: When loaded via HTTP, what should the path be for your assets? Is it `http://whatever/views/css/chunk-common.45fe69c2.css` or `http://whatever/application/views/css/chunk-common.45fe69c2.css` or something else?

Comment: Yeah, the path must be: http://whatever/application/views/css/chunk-common.45fe69c2.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to access static assets under the base URL `http://example.com/application/views/...`, you'll want to set the [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) property in your config

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  outputDir: 'views',
  publicPath: '/application/views/',
  // ...
}
```

---

FYI, if you ever do want to use [`assetsDir`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir), don't prefix it with `./`

> A directory (**relative to `outputDir`**) to nest generated static assets (js, css, img, fonts) under.

An example would be

```js
assetsDir: 'assets'
```

which would dump files in `views/assets/css`, `views/assets/js`, etc.